# Do Cron Job need MTA when sending email with PHPMailer

Tags: php, cron, postfix

I'm using CRON Job to send an email alert to the user when it is near the submission due date. But when I want to test it with sending a simple email first, it keeps showing `(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)` in the `syslog`. But when I run the PHP script using URL, it is able to send the email to me.

So my question is, do I need a MTA installed on my web server when running CRON Job to send email with PHPMailer?

This is my `crontab` code:

```
* * * * * /var/www/html/test.php (cmd1;  cmd2) 2>&1 | logger -t mycmd
```

And this is my `test.php` code:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '/usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require '/usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '/usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

require '/usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer/autoload.php';

// Set the script time zone to UTC
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

function sendMail($email, $message, $subject) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    // set up for the SMTP and used account
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'test@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'password';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    // Disable some SSL check
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );

    // sender, recipient, reply-to etc
    $mail->SetFrom('replyto@gmail.com', 'Reply-to');
    $mail->addAddress("$email");
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    // email contains
    $mail->Subject = "$subject";
    $mail->Body = $message;

    // send email
    $mail->send();
}

sendMail("test@gmail.com", "Hello World!", "Test");
?>
```

Comment: Can you post the error you get?

Comment: Run you script in console. Any errors?